# how to replace empty table cell in word 2007with '-'?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

How to replace empty table cell in word with '-'? It seems it's impossible to locate empty cell in word table , please note empty=nothing in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Word does not have a simple way of finding empty cells. In fact, you'll have to do some VBA.

From http://word.tips.net/T010772_Placing_Text_in_Empty_Table_Cells.html, I find 2 methods: 1 to replace all empty table cells in all empty tables:

```
Sub ProcCells1()
    Dim tTable As Table
    Dim cCell As Cell
    Dim sTemp As String

    sTemp = "-"

    For Each tTable In ActiveDocument.Range.Tables
        For Each cCell In tTable.Range.Cells
            'An apparently empty cell contains an end of cell marker
            If Len(cCell.Range.Text) < 3 Then
                cCell.Range = sTemp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Set oCell = Nothing
    Set tTable = Nothing
End Sub
```

The other method only does the currently selected table:

```
Sub ProcCells2()
    Dim tTable As Table
    Dim cCell As Cell
    Dim sTemp As String

    sTemp = "-"

    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        Set tTable = Selection.Tables(1)
        For Each cCell In tTable.Range.Cells
            'An apparently empty cell contains an end of cell marker
            If Len(cCell.Range.Text) < 3 Then
                cCell.Range = sTemp
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Set oCell = Nothing
    Set tTable = Nothing
End Sub
```

Another option is to copy your table to Excel, use the advanced select features there to select all empty cells and add the dash there. Then you can copy the table back to word.

Comment: Do you mean there is no default option to locate empty cell in word 2007,such as in 'replace' function, it allow you to choose different locate options, in excel 2007, you can find 'empty' option under the 'more' option

Comment: @huiwang Word does not have a simple option to find empty cells. Excel does because it's much more focused on data than on formatting compared to Word. Excel data often requires you to select empty cells for the same reason as you do, but Word has that far less often, since you're more likely to deal with strings than with numbers.

Comment: @ nate I am satisfied with your answer, how do i vote you and close this question?

Comment: @huiwang You need a minor amount of rep to upvote an answer, but you can accept it by clicking the checkmark below the vote count. This gives me a small amount of rep, gives you a tiny amount of rep, and marks the answer for the community at large that you think this answer is the best.

Comment: i got it, thank you very much for your help,wish you a nice mooncake festival! But i already clicked on the checkmark, why the count is still zero?